# c# ряд тейлора, лабораторная

Tags: c#

не могу изменить часть кода под свое задание, так как не понимаю что от меня требуется. Помогите изменить выделенную часть под задание.

**Само задание -**

Вычислить значение функции, заданной с помощью ряда Тейлора с точность eps (задается пользователем). По итогам вычисления вывести на экран:

- значение аргумента, для которого выполнялось вычисление;
- значение функции;
- точность (eps);
- количество просуммированных членов ряда.

[image: задание]

Используя условие лабораторной задачи № 2 реализовать измененный алгоритм со следующими особенностями:

1. Дополнительно у пользователя спрашивается xнач и xкон и шаг dx (шаг изменения);
2. В тексте программы происходит вычисление для всех указанных значений x и результаты вычислений выводится в формате таблицы.

Мой код:

```
using System;
 
namespace TaylorSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Ввод данных пользователя
                double x_start, x_end, eps, dx;
                Console.Write("Введите начальное значение x, при x > 1: ");
                x_start = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Введите конечное значение x, при x > 1: ");
                x_end = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (x_start > 1 && x_end > 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите точность: ");
                    eps = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Введите шаг: ");
                    dx = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    // Вывод введённых данных пользователю
                    Console.WriteLine("\nНачальное значение х: {0}\n" +
                                      "Конечное значение х: {1}\n" +
                                      "Точность (eps): {2}\n" +
                                      "Шаг (dx): {3}\n" +
                                      "\nВыходные данные: \n" +
                                      "_________________________", x_start, x_end, eps, dx);
                    // Основной алгоритм. Вычисление приблизительного значения и значения функции.
                    //ОТСЮДА
                    //НУЖНО
                    //ИЗМЕНИТЬ
                    while (x_start < x_end)
                    {
                        double function = 0, n = 1;
                        int count = 0;
                        while (Math.Abs((Math.Pow(-1, n) * Math.Pow(x_start, n))) > eps)
                        {
                            function += (Math.Pow(-1, n) * Math.Pow(x_start, n)) / n;
                            n++;
                            count++;
                        }
                    //И 
                    //ДО
                    //СЮДА
                        // Вывод выходных данных
                        Console.WriteLine("\nx: {0}\n" +
                                          "f(x): {1}\n" +
                                          "Количество членов ряда: {2}\n" +
                                          "_________________________", x_start, function, count);
                        x_start += dx;
                    }
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Аргумент x должен быть в интервале x > 1");
            }
            //  Проверка на ввод
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы ничего не ввели или ввели не число!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам помог мой ответ, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ", нажав на галочку  слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, вам нужно получать значение ряда Тейлора с точность до `eps` в точке `x_start` изменяя его на `dx`.

То есть в самом цикле `while(x_start <= x_end)` нужно выводить 4 пункта, которые у вас в начале вопроса написаны.

Для этого лучше вынести вычисление значения в точке `x_start` в отдельную функцию, а через ссылку передавать кол-во членов ряда.

Например так:

```
static double getValueTaylor(double x, double eps, ref int count)
{
    double function = Math.PI / 2, n = 1, slag = 0;
    count = 0;
    do
    {
        count++;
        slag = Math.Pow(-1, count % 2) / (Math.Pow(x, n) * n);
        function += slag;
        n += 2;
    } while (Math.Abs(slag) > eps) ;
    return function;
}
```

Немного переделал вычисление значения т.к. у вас было много в чем ошибки, надеюсь код понятен.

В самой функции `main`:

```
int count = 0;
double function = 0;
while (x_start <= x_end)
{
    function = getValueTaylor(x_start, eps, ref count);
    // Вывод выходных данных
    Console.WriteLine("\nx: {0}\n" +
                      "f(x): {1}\n" +
                      "eps: {2}\n" +
                      "Количество членов ряда: {3}\n" +
                      "_________________________", 
                      x_start, function, eps, count);
    x_start += dx;
}
```